# Why is the browser taking so long to load my JSON file with my jQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having kind of an odd issue with my jQuery JSON script. When I access the json file directly in the browser, it loads instantly. However, when I load it with jQUery $.getJSON, it takes an extremely long time to load. Oddly enough, the function inside $.getJSON works instantly when I click on the "Network" tab in Chrome's developer console. Say I have the page freshly loaded with the developer console already open... I begin typing in my search criteria input and nothing happens. The JSON file is not listed. Then I click on the network tab again and the JSON file loads with the file url at the bottom of the list in the network tab. I am SO confused... am I doing something wrong?  Note that this is inside wordpress. Not sure if that makes a difference. Here is my code...

The JavaScript:

```
<script>
(function($){
    $('[data-search-criteria]').on('change', function(){
        $.getJSON( "<?php echo JZ_PLUGIN_URL.'/includes/service_ajax.php';?>?search="+encodeURIComponent($(this).val())+"&include-partners=false", function(data){
             $('[data-search-results]').first().text('');
              $.each(data, function(i, post){
                  $('[data-search-results]').first().append(
                    $('<div></div>').addClass('media').append(
                        $('<h3></h3>').text(post.post_title)
                    )
                  )
              });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The JSON output if I type 'Sal'

```
[ {
    "ID": 95, 
    "post_author": "1", 
    "post_date": "2017-12-03 03:17:56", 
    "post_date_gmt": "2017-12-03 03:17:56", 
    "post_content": "[service-profile]", 
    "post_title": "Sally's Catering", 
    "post_excerpt": "", 
    "post_status": "publish", 
    "comment_status": "closed", 
    "ping_status": "closed", 
    "post_password": "", 
    "post_name": "sallys-catering", 
    "to_ping": "", "pinged": "", 
    "post_modified": "2018-02-26 16:02:50", 
    "post_modified_gmt": "2018-02-26 16:02:50", 
    "post_content_filtered": "", 
    "post_parent": 0, 
    "guid": "http:\/\/jadezebra.dev\/service\/sallys-catering\/", 
    "menu_order": 0, 
    "post_type": "service", 
    "post_mime_type": "", 
    "comment_count": "1", 
    "filter": "raw"
} ]
```

Comment: Have you dropped in some `console.log()` calls so that you can tell when the callback is invoked?

Comment: Are you sure it is the request or the processing. Simple logging can give yu the times of how long actions take.

Comment: How many rows are there typically in the response?

Comment: to rule out a browser issue, try a different browser

Comment: How many elements match `'[data-search-criteria]'`? You repeat the query several times; it might be better to cache that in a variable a la `var result = $('[data-search-criteria]').first();`.

Comment: I added a console log right after the on change call and then again right after the getJSON call. Both logs appeared when I typed in the input, but it took forever for them to even appear in the log. Also, the problem happens in MS Edge.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event only triggers in response to some actions, like focus change or click (it is also browser dependent). If you want an event that kicks in with every user-modification to the input (whether it be with the keyboard, the mouse, context menu, ...), then use the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

There is nothing you can do about the retrieval itself (i.e. `$.getJSON`), unless you make the server return the data in chunks: then you would only get back the first 10 results (for example), and would need to make a next Ajax request (with a page argument) to get the next 10 results, etc. Obviously this requires changes to your PHP code, which should be made aware of the new page parameter and the chunk size, and make queries accordingly (in MySql you would use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` keywords for that).

If the delay is more (or also) due to the processing of the data, then you could just display one element at a time and use `setTimeout` to allow the display to be updated before continuing with the next item:

```
(function($){
    $('[data-search-criteria]').on('change', function(){
        var timer;
        clearTimeout(timer); // Interrupt any ongoing processing of a previous response
        $container = $('[data-search-results]').first();
        $.getJSON( "<?php echo JZ_PLUGIN_URL.'/includes/service_ajax.php';?>?search="+encodeURIComponent($(this).val())+"&include-partners=false", function(data){
            $container.text('');
            (function loop(i) {
                if (i >= data.length) return; // all done;
                var post = data[i];
                $container.append(
                    $('<div></div>').addClass('media').append(
                        $('<h3></h3>').text(post.post_title)
                    )
                );
                timer = setTimeout(loop.bind(null, i+1));
            })(0); // Immediately invoked function expression
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There are only 6 total rows in the database so I can't imagine the problem being with the server side script. I tried your code but it still takes about 15 seconds for the getJSON to execute and for the logs to appear.

Comment: Is it your server, or are you using hosting services? If the latter, could you reproduce the server on you own PC and see if you then still get such crazy delays?

Comment: Its in WAMP server. As I mentioned in the original question, if I access the script that returns the JSON data directly with the same search criteria, it loads instantly.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the getJSON loads instantly if I switch to another browser tab and then switch back. Could it be a problem with the .on('change') call?

Comment: Well of course, the whole function will only kick in on a `change` event. If you want to have it run with every change in the input, then use the `input` event instead.

Comment: Hmm I thought that's what the change event did. I can't find anything on the input event on the jquery api docs. Well I replaced change with input and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Events are not defined by jQuery, but the DOM. Look at [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)